# Displaying form inputs using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want write jquery code that will show form inputs after a checkbox is checked. This is how I have formated the form inputs. What is the best way of doing this?

```
    echo '<li class="checkbox_item">'. form_label('Number of bedrooms','bedrooms'). form_checkbox('bedrooms','yes'). form_error('bedrooms').'</li>';
    echo '<li class="input_item" id=no_rooms>'. form_label('Number of bedrooms','bedrooms'). form_input('bedrooms'). form_error('bedrooms').'</li>';

    echo '<li class="checkbox_item">'. form_label('Number of bathfooms','bathrooms'). form_checkbox('bathrooms'). form_error('bathrooms').'</li>';
    echo '<li class="input_item">'. form_label('Number of bathfooms','bathrooms'). form_input('bathrooms'). form_error('bathrooms').'</li>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
//hide all inputs
$('.input_item').hide()

//when a checkbox is ticked, hide/unihde next li 
$('.checkbox_item input').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').next('.input_item').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ttyx8/1/

EDIT (i added a selector to next so that the code is better)

Comment: Nicola's answer is the best answer in that it is very straightforward and would serve most purposes, a more elaborate way would be to load the fields into the dom using the get() function or actively building them and inserting via the html() function. The benefit to doing it that way is that the fields wouldn't be in the DOM unless they were actually needed. Pretty minor for a few checkboxes, but if you were replacing or loading a  lot of data or elements it might be beneficial. Also this method would allow for more dynamic stuff (conditional sets of checkboxes based on other inputs)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. thanks. I also didn't know the jsfiddle site. I think it will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do is to use the "change()" event and "toggle()" function. 
You can bind the "change()" event to the checkbox, once triggered, "toggle" the display of the target element.

Example in the following have one checkbox, once checked, an input field will display. Once unchecked, the input field will hide.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' 
      src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectroom').change(function(){
        $('#chooseroom').toggle();
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>
 Select bedrooms <input type='checkbox' id='selectroom'/>
</p>
<p id='chooseroom' style='display:none;'>
 How many bedrooms? <input type='text' name='roomnumber'/>
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using a different Id for each checkbox and input. I need something that will work for all of checkboxes and inputs